# Como remover extensão Essentials Web do visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Eu adicionei esta extensão no Visual Studio 2015 para testar, mais ela desabilita todos os comandos nativos do visual Studio, eu queria remover isso para nunca mais instalar.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361

Conseguir retira este lixo em Tools / Extension and Updates, mais o visual Studio não retornou como antes, não completa nada no código cshtml

Comment: Nunca tive este problema. Já tentou reparar o Visual Studio?

Comment: Como eu posso fazer isso? agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca ouvi dizer que o Web Essentials desabilita comandos do Visual Studio. Deve ser alguma outra coisa.

Experimente reparar a instalação do Visual Studio. Em **Programas e Recursos**, encontre seu Visual Studio e clique em **Alterar**:

[image: Programas e Recursos]

[image: Repair]

Comment: não retornou 100% mais já ajudou bastante